# R repetead ads for property index

Tags: r

I am trying to generate something like a price index but I am struggling to do it. The data I have is something like the following:

```
       ID     POSTED      START        END  PRICE
851073112 2020-06-13 2020-04-23 2020-10-31 150000
851073743 2020-05-28 2020-04-23 2020-05-30 17651
851073743 2020-04-30 2020-02-17 2020-05-30 18623
851073813 2020-04-30 2019-12-17 2020-05-30 15730
851073874 2020-04-30 2020-04-23 2020-10-18 45355
851073900 2020-04-30 2019-10-29 2020-05-30 20156
851073900 2020-05-28 2020-04-23 2020-05-30 15624
851073973 2020-04-30 2019-10-29 2020-05-30 45322

...
```

So these are ads for houses that were posted when `POSTED` says, and `START` and `END` refers to the days in which the website algorithm will keep the ad online. However, if someone changes the price, it will appear as another observation (with the same `ID`) like with `ID = 851073743`. I want to create a monthly index so for month 2020-05 it calculates the average price not only of ads posted on that month, but also of those that are still active then.

So I have two problems: first, how can I calculate the average of the price of all active ads in a month? Second, how can I deal with the fact that I have "repeated" `ID`s? For example, I want to use `PRICE = 18623` in 2020-04 index, but `PRICE = 17651` in 2020-05 index for `ID = 851073743`.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. It is easier for others to help if you post a sample of your data using `dput(head(data))`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using the `tidyverse` package.

Add year/month index

```
data_ym <- data %>%
   mutate(MONTH_YR = format(as.Date(POSTED), "%Y-%m"))
```

Average `PRICE` for a given year/month.

```
data_ym %>%
   group_by(MONTH_YR) %>%
   summarize(PRICE_AVE = mean(PRICE))
```

Average `PRICE` for a given year/month within a specific `ID`

```
data_ym %>%
   group_by(MONTH_YR, ID) %>%
   summarize(PRICE_AVE = mean(PRICE))
```